# How to convert english "abc123 " digits to arabic "ابث١٢٣ " dynamically android

Tags: java, android, arabic, digits

**UPDATED**

i have been looking for solution but couldnt found it yet ..

i have tried this

```
// Check for language
    String tempLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    if (tempLang == "ar") {
        Locale AR_LOCALE_EAST_NUMBERS = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-u-nu-arab").build();
        Locale.setDefault(AR_LOCALE_EAST_NUMBERS);

        firstName.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(getActivity().getString(R.string.input_charatars_only_valid)));
    } else {

        firstName.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(getActivity().getString(R.string.input_charatars_only_valid)));
    }
```

1. first of all it gives error of API .. it says to use

   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
2. i want to use it for 15 API as my minSdk is 15

is it correct or any changes needed

**UPDATED** :

kindly also tell how to convert the digits in english as

"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789 " and a sapce also ""

what would be done to convert the string to arabic with abc,123 & a space ?

PS : i am new here kindly ignore is any mistake is done ..
thanks

Comment: @Mark sorry but i have updated my question now with full explanation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with `replaceAll`.

First, create a method:

```
    public String convertToArabic(int value)
{
    String newValue = (((((((((((value+"")
            .replaceAll("1", "١")).replaceAll("2", "٢"))
            .replaceAll("3", "٣")).replaceAll("4", "٤"))
            .replaceAll("5", "٥")).replaceAll("6", "٦"))
            .replaceAll("7", "٧")).replaceAll("8", "٨"))
            .replaceAll("9", "٩")).replaceAll("0", "٠"));
    return newValue;
}
```

And usage:

```
String myArabicNumber= convertToArabic(123);
Log.d("output",myArabicNumber);
```

output:

```
١٢٣
```

**UPDATE:**

you can do it by concatenating them:

```
    String space = "\u00A0"; //space
    String myArabicCharacter = getResources().getString(R.string.help);
    String myArabicNumber= convertToArabic(123);
    String fullHomework = myArabicCharacter+space+myArabicNumber;
    Log.d("output",fullHomework);
```

output:

```
     راهنما ١٢٣
```

**Update2**

```
YourProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-ar/
           strings.xml

arabic string resource:
    <string name="help">راهنما</string>

english string resource:
    <string name="help">help</string>
```

Comment: @AtifAfridi try updated answer

Comment: yes but i want to convert the "abc123 " .. string and number conversion is clear but how can i covert "abc" to arabic "ا ب ث" or i have to use a different string for arabic ??

Comment: @AtifAfridi  you cannot do that. instead, you can use different string resources

Comment: @AtifAfridi   look at the last update

Comment: thanks .. i am accepting ur ans but u have to reply if i have update in near future .. but i think its solved now :) thanks for ur time

Comment: String numericArabic = convertToArabic(0123456789);

it gives error of  "Integer number is too long"

Answer (score 2):

use ascii character convert

convert number EN to AR

```
public static String convertNumberEnglishToArabic(String input) {

        String value = "";

        for (char character : input.toCharArray()) {

            String str = "";
            int ascii = (int) character;

            if (ascii >= 49 && ascii <= 51) {
                //english number
                int valueOld = ascii + 1584;
                char valueChar = (char) valueOld;
                str = String.valueOf(valueChar);
            } else {
                //default
                str = String.valueOf(character);
            }

            value += str;
        }
        return value;
}
```

for convert number from AR to EN

```
public String converNumberArabicToEnglish(String input) {

        String value = "";

        for (char character : input.toCharArray()) {

            String str = "";
            int ascii = (int) character;
            if (ascii >= 1632 && ascii <= 1641) {
                //arabic number
                int valueOld = ascii - 1584;
                char valueChar = (char) valueOld;
                str = String.valueOf(valueChar);
            } else {
                //default
                str = String.valueOf(character);
            }

            value += str;
        }
        return value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur kind reply .. i have updated the question can u check now plz